# Android mSensorManager.registerListener listener stops getting called

Tags: android

I've got an Android app that registers a listener to a TYPE_ORIENTATION sensor. The registered method gets call for a while but then stops. It starts getting called again when I view the app again. I put the app back into the background and the registered event continues for a time ( ~ one minute?) and then again stops getting called.

My registeration code:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

The registered method:

```
private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
            float pitch = se.values[1];
            float roll = se.values[2];

            long deltaTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - gestureStartTime;
            if (deltaTime > 6000 )
                gestureCnt = 0;

            switch(gestureCnt)
            {
                case 0: // wait for initial position, flat
                    if ( roll < 10 && roll > -10  ) {
                        gestureStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        gestureCnt = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1: case 3:
                if ( roll > 60 || roll < -60 ) {
                    gestureCnt++;
                }
                break;
                case 2: case 4:
                if ( roll < 10 && roll > -10 ) {
                    gestureCnt++;
                }
                if ( gestureCnt == 5) {
                    Intent localIntent = new Intent(Constants.SMS_MSG);
                    localIntent.putExtra(Constants.SMS_PLAY_ACTION, "play");
                    // Broadcasts the Intent to receivers in this app.
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
                    gestureCnt = 0;
                    gestureStartTime = 0;
                }
                break;
            }

        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    };
```

I am testing with a Pixel 5a connected and debugging with the Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Activities in the background are killed after a short time.  1 or 2 minutes.  That would include any registered sensor listeners.

Comment: I think I have my app setup properly to run as a service. How do things like gps loggers that record hiking/biking/etc tracks do it?

Comment: They run a Foreground service.  Not a regular service.  And not an Activity. (This is on modern Android.  Answers could be different in the past).